# Is this the most "general" way of implementing a tree structure using RealmSwift?

Tags: swift, realm

newbie to realm, I was wondering about how to build a tree structure using RealmSwift...

I tend to think about this as a mimic of a filesystem's folder idea, so,

```
class Folder: Object {
    dynamic var record = false
    dynamic var uuid = ""
    dynamic var title = ""
    let members = List<Folder>()
}

class Root: Object {
    dynamic var uuid = ""
    dynamic var title = "/"
    let members = List<Folder>()
}
```

I'd only have one Root, and then would implement various tree-walking, folder-manipulation, and so on. If Folder.record is false, the folder node is a "directory", if it's true, the folder node is a "file"

oh wizards of RealmSwift, am I on the right track to build a tree structure using RealmSwift??

Answer (score 5):

If you want model a filesystem with files and folders, it will probably be simpler to do it like this:

```
class File: Object {
    dynamic var uuid  = ""
    dynamic var title = ""
}

class Folder: Object {
    dynamic var uuid  = ""
    dynamic var title = ""
    let files   = List<File>()
    let folders = List<Folder>()
}
```

Instead of an explicit root class, you could use the first first Folder object (accessible as `realm.objects(Folder).first()`).

Comment: and so I am using a structure very similar to this, but when I go more that 3-4 levels deep, I get <Maximum depth exceeded> in my lists.... I am filling the "tree" from a JSON structure, it's only about 6 levels deep.